# Ajustar Background conforme resolução

Tags: css

Tenho uma imagem de fundo, e gostaria que ela preenchesse a div e se ajuste conforme a resolução do monitor.

A div já é responsiva pois uso Foundation Zurb.

Fiz isso, mas a imagem não fica ajustada.

```
background: url('../img/fundos/fundo.png')no-repeat center top;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu uso Foundation também e o seguinte trecho testado em Chrome e Firefox atualizados:

```
// supondo um identificador tipo classe para sua div
.my-div{
   background-image: url(../img/fundos/fundo.png);
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Para saber mais sobre propriedades de imagem de fundo em CSS3, suporte e uso de prefixos [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)